¿Como obtener todos los valores de que coinciden en una lista en Excel?
Disculpen estoy algo perdido en Excel y me solicitaron lo siguiente en esta tabla:



A
B
C
RESULTADO




0001
P
0001
P,C


0001
C
0002
C,A


0002
C




0002
A




0002
C




0002
C





Lo que tengo que hacer es buscar el valor C en toda la columna A y traer todos los valores en B sin repetir, no sé si puedan apoyarme con alguna función, yo hice esta pero solo me trae el primer valor que encuentra: SI(COINCIDIR(C1;A:A);B:B;"")
y quisiera traer todos los valores de B donde se encuentre C en A

Pusiste la etiqueta "excel-2010", yo tengo una solución pero no estoy seguro si te sirve para esa versión --> =UNIRCADENAS(", ";VERDADERO;UNICOS(FILTRAR(B:B;A:A=C2)))

El usuario usa Excel 2010

Con Excel 2010 no puedes. Necesitas una macro para obtener el resultado que deseas
